Why tailwindcss layout with flex does not work on iPads?
I have 4 blocks of label/checkbox and I want:

On small devices to show 1 block.
On iPads show 2 blocks.
On all big devices to show all 4 blocks

With html like :
<div class="sm:flex">
  <div class="w-full sm:w-12/12 md:w-6/12 xl:w-3/12 p-1 pl-2 pr-2 mt-1">
    <div class="flex">
      <span class="mr-2">In news: </span>
      <div class="relative inline-block w-10 mr-2 align-middle select-none transition duration-200 ease-in d2">
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model.live="inNews" name="inNews" id="inNews" class="toggle-checkbox absolute block w-6 h-6 rounded-full bg-white border-4 appearance-none cursor-pointer" />
        <label for="toggle" class="toggle-label block overflow-hidden h-6 rounded-full bg-gray-300 cursor-pointer"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w-full sm:w-12/12 md:w-6/12 xl:w-3/12 p-1 pl-2 pr-2 mt-1">
    <div class="flex">
      <span class="mr-2">In users: </span>
      <div class="relative inline-block w-10 mr-2 align-middle select-none transition duration-200 ease-in d2">
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model.live="inUsers" name="inUsers" id="inUsers" class="toggle-checkbox absolute block w-6 h-6 rounded-full bg-white border-4 appearance-none cursor-pointer" />
        <label for="toggle" class="toggle-label block overflow-hidden h-6 rounded-full bg-gray-300 cursor-pointer"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w-full sm:w-12/12 md:w-6/12 xl:w-3/12 p-1 pl-2 pr-2 mt-1">
    <div class="flex">
      <span class="mr-2">In app images: </span>
      <div class="relative inline-block w-10 mr-2 align-middle select-none transition duration-200 ease-in d2">
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model.live="inAppImages" name="inAppImages" id="inAppImages" class="toggle-checkbox absolute block w-6 h-6 rounded-full bg-white border-4 appearance-none cursor-pointer" />
        <label for="toggle" class="toggle-label block overflow-hidden h-6 rounded-full bg-gray-300 cursor-pointer"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w-full sm:w-12/12 md:w-6/12 xl:w-3/12 p-1 pl-2 pr-2 mt-1">
    <div class="flex">
      <span class="mr-2">In news categories: </span>
      <div class="relative inline-block w-10 mr-2 align-middle select-none transition duration-200 ease-in d2">
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model.live="inNewsCategories" name="inNewsCategories" id="inNewsCategories" class="toggle-checkbox absolute block w-6 h-6 rounded-full bg-white border-4 appearance-none cursor-pointer" />
        <label for="toggle" class="toggle-label block overflow-hidden h-6 rounded-full bg-gray-300 cursor-pointer"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

However, it does not work on iPads – I have 4 blocks anyway.
How to fix it ?
"laravel/framework": "^10.48.7",
"tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
"livewire/livewire": "^3.4.10",


There could be a couple things happening.
The most likely cause is that you don't have flex-wrap set on the container so the items don't automatically move to a new line.


<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.0.5/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="sm:flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="w-full md:w-6/12 xl:w-3/12 p-1 pl-2 pr-2 mt-1">
    <div class="flex">
      <span class="mr-2">In news: </span>
      <div class="relative inline-block w-10 mr-2 align-middle select-none transition duration-200 ease-in d2">
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model.live="inNews" name="inNews" id="inNews" class="toggle-checkbox absolute block w-6 h-6 rounded-full bg-white border-4 appearance-none cursor-pointer" />
        <label for="toggle" class="toggle-label block overflow-hidden h-6 rounded-full bg-gray-300 cursor-pointer"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w-full sm:w-12/12 md:w-6/12 xl:w-3/12 p-1 pl-2 pr-2 mt-1">
    <div class="flex">
      <span class="mr-2">In users: </span>
      <div class="relative inline-block w-10 mr-2 align-middle select-none transition duration-200 ease-in d2">
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model.live="inUsers" name="inUsers" id="inUsers" class="toggle-checkbox absolute block w-6 h-6 rounded-full bg-white border-4 appearance-none cursor-pointer" />
        <label for="toggle" class="toggle-label block overflow-hidden h-6 rounded-full bg-gray-300 cursor-pointer"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w-full sm:w-12/12 md:w-6/12 xl:w-3/12 p-1 pl-2 pr-2 mt-1">
    <div class="flex">
      <span class="mr-2">In app images: </span>
      <div class="relative inline-block w-10 mr-2 align-middle select-none transition duration-200 ease-in d2">
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model.live="inAppImages" name="inAppImages" id="inAppImages" class="toggle-checkbox absolute block w-6 h-6 rounded-full bg-white border-4 appearance-none cursor-pointer" />
        <label for="toggle" class="toggle-label block overflow-hidden h-6 rounded-full bg-gray-300 cursor-pointer"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w-full sm:w-12/12 md:w-6/12 xl:w-3/12 p-1 pl-2 pr-2 mt-1">
    <div class="flex">
      <span class="mr-2">In news categories: </span>
      <div class="relative inline-block w-10 mr-2 align-middle select-none transition duration-200 ease-in d2">
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model.live="inNewsCategories" name="inNewsCategories" id="inNewsCategories" class="toggle-checkbox absolute block w-6 h-6 rounded-full bg-white border-4 appearance-none cursor-pointer" />
        <label for="toggle" class="toggle-label block overflow-hidden h-6 rounded-full bg-gray-300 cursor-pointer"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Other than that, it depends on whether you are using a standard tailwind config as well as the iPad you're designing for.

iPad Pro has a screen resolution of 1024x1366 (This is the lg breakpoint when viewed in portrait, and xl when viewed in landscape)
iPad Air has a screen resolution of 820x1180 (This is the md breakpoint when viewed in portrait, and lg when viewed in landscape)
iPad Mini has a screen resolution of 768x1024 (This is the md breakpoint when viewed in portrait, and lg when viewed in landscape)

Hope this helps!

Using grid utility perfectly fits your needs.
Instead of making the parent flex then modify each child width independently, grid will make sure that all children have the same width, you only modify how many columns you want to have on each screen size.
For example: when you want to show only two columns on iPad (meduim screen), you will add md:grid-cols-2


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4">
  <div class="p-1 pl-2 pr-2 mt-1">
    <div class="flex">
      <span class="mr-2">In news: </span>
      <div class="relative inline-block w-10 mr-2 align-middle select-none transition duration-200 ease-in d2">
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model.live="inNews" name="inNews" id="inNews" class="toggle-checkbox absolute block w-6 h-6 rounded-full bg-white border-4 appearance-none cursor-pointer" />
        <label for="toggle" class="toggle-label block overflow-hidden h-6 rounded-full bg-gray-300 cursor-pointer"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="p-1 pl-2 pr-2 mt-1">
    <div class="flex">
      <span class="mr-2">In users: </span>
      <div class="relative inline-block w-10 mr-2 align-middle select-none transition duration-200 ease-in d2">
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model.live="inUsers" name="inUsers" id="inUsers" class="toggle-checkbox absolute block w-6 h-6 rounded-full bg-white border-4 appearance-none cursor-pointer" />
        <label for="toggle" class="toggle-label block overflow-hidden h-6 rounded-full bg-gray-300 cursor-pointer"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="p-1 pl-2 pr-2 mt-1">
    <div class="flex">
      <span class="mr-2">In app images: </span>
      <div class="relative inline-block w-10 mr-2 align-middle select-none transition duration-200 ease-in d2">
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model.live="inAppImages" name="inAppImages" id="inAppImages" class="toggle-checkbox absolute block w-6 h-6 rounded-full bg-white border-4 appearance-none cursor-pointer" />
        <label for="toggle" class="toggle-label block overflow-hidden h-6 rounded-full bg-gray-300 cursor-pointer"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="p-1 pl-2 pr-2 mt-1">
    <div class="flex">
      <span class="mr-2">In news categories: </span>
      <div class="relative inline-block w-10 mr-2 align-middle select-none transition duration-200 ease-in d2">
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model.live="inNewsCategories" name="inNewsCategories" id="inNewsCategories" class="toggle-checkbox absolute block w-6 h-6 rounded-full bg-white border-4 appearance-none cursor-pointer" />
        <label for="toggle" class="toggle-label block overflow-hidden h-6 rounded-full bg-gray-300 cursor-pointer"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



